# How to appear element at X px, in this case?

Tags: html, css, responsive

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {

    #hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

}

#hamburger {
    display: none;
}
```

but this doesn't work (#hamburger never appears) so I don't know what to do because in theory the code is supposed to work,
here is another part of the code

```css
#hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.navbar .checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.navbar .hamburger-lines {
    display: flex;
    height: 26px;
    width: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  }
```

the error may be in there but I don't understand

here is the html

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Skills">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#AboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="hamburger">
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="" />

            <div class="hamburger-lines">
                <span class="line line1"></span>
                <span class="line line2"></span>
                <span class="line line3"></span>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

if necessary : https://github.com/August7337/website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of CSS rules is important when two rules have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The `#hamburger` rule inside the media query is before the one without, so the `display: none` will always take precedence. Instead, reorder the rules so that the rule within the media query is after the one without:

```css
#hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Skills">SKILLS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#AboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="hamburger">
    Hamburger
  </div>
</nav>
```